# How to configure the Gstreamer audio sink to use the virtual sink

Tags: gstreamer, audio-streaming, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to stream audio to a virtual audio sink that I created.

---

I created the virtual audio sink using

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=virtsink sink_properties=device.description=Virtual_Sink
```

Now all I need to do is to configure the gstreamer client to use the sink that I created. I was able to get it working with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ... ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

and selecting `Virtual_Sink` as the Output Device via Settings>Sound>Output. This works because `autoaudiosink` selects the default system output when I alter the Output device.

**Is there a way to achieve the same thing without having to modify the system's Sound settings?**

---

I tried this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=<udp-port> \
caps="..." \
! rtpL24depay \
! audioconvert \
! audioresample \
! alsasink \
device=virtsink
```

But I am getting an error:

> Playback open error on device 'virtsink': No such file or directory

---

Comment: You may set default audio sink with `pactl set-default-sink virtsink`. Or use pulsesink: `gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! pulsesink device-name=virtsink`

Comment: In the question, I said I can solve the problem by setting the default sink, but I want GStreamer to use virtsink without having to modify the system's audio settings.

Comment: The second proposal using programatic pulsesink's device-name property setting is neither applicable ? You may better explain your case.